# How can I use my parameter in query annotation in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, annotations

I created a MySQL query as a string. I want to add it to my `@Query` annotation. I could not get the parameter from my function. I tried `:query` in repository `findAllFaces` function `@Query` but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `?0`, `?1`, `?{index of parameter}`....
Try this:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT f.id FROM faces f WHERE ?0", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findAllFaces(String query);
```

Another example:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM faces WHERE key1 = ?0 AND key2 = ?1 AND key3 = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findByKey1AndKey2AndKey3(String value1, String value2, String value3);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1")
  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

**Solution 2:**

```java
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmailAddress",
  query = "select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1")
public class User {

}
```

Reference document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries.annotation-based-configuration